# Font not applied in my web application

Tags: css, grails, font-face, gsp

I am working on `grails` web application in which I am trying to apply a `font` named `open sans` but it is not applied in my web application. The procedure which I have followed is:

I have put the code below in me extended.css file

```
@font-face {
    src: url('../../images/font/openSans.woff');
    font-family: 'open sans';
    /*url('openSans.woff') format('woff'),*/
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
}

body{
    font-family: 'open sans';
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You might be missing the font, to begin with. Is it really availabe at the relative URL specified?

Comment: My IDE shows that font file is available.

Comment: What matters is whether the font file is found by a browser. Use a browser’s developer tools to check what happens (network log, error log).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Open Sans` is a Google font, you can use it in you application as described in the [link](http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aOpen+Sans).

Add following to your view or layout

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

The Google Fonts API will generate the necessary browser-specific CSS to use the fonts. All you need to do is add the font name to your CSS styles. For example:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

See example [here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started).

Answer (score 0):

Download your font from any website.
got to [webFont Generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). 
It will generate a zip file . in which got to your .css file and copy and paste code in your web within style tag. also paste all file within same directory. it will run all browser.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Philosopher';
src: url('WebRoot/fonts/philosopher-regular.eot');
src: url('WebRoot/fonts/philosopher-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('WebRoot/fonts/philosopher-regular.woff') format('woff'),
     url('WebRoot/fonts/philosopher-regular.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

body{
font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "Philosopher";
}
```

this code snippet is true for philospher font. You can use any font based on this example.
Enjoy.