# Installed fonts in Grails not working

Tags: css, grails, fonts

I want to use the font Open Sans on my Grails project, so I placed the fonts in the web-app directory under the 'fonts' folder. Afterwards, I added this to my CSS:

```
body{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'OpenSans', arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

but it still won't work. Initially, I used the link href from Google fonts and placed it in the  of my main.gsp... didn't work.

Comment: have u added the `font-face` in your css https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face

Answer (score 1):

Add following to your view or layout

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

The Google Fonts API will generate the necessary browser-specific CSS to use the fonts. All you need to do is add the font name to your CSS styles. For example:

```
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
```

Ref:- [Font not applied in my web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048806/font-not-applied-in-my-web-application/19796005#19796005)

Answer (score 0):

If your `.css` file is in a folder then write the following code at the beginning of your `.css` file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  src: url('../font/yourfontname.eot');
  src: url('../font/yourfontname.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../font/yourfontname.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../font/yourfontname.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../font/yourfontname.svg#MuseoSans100') format('svg');
}
```

so use `../font/yourfontname.eot`